# No Testimony matches the given query

Tags: django

I am trying to set up a comment function for each individual instance with valid id's. But i am getting "No Testimony matches the given query" by clicking the link below.[image] 
Any help is appreciated.

template

```
<a href="{% url 'commentform' testimony.id %}">Make a comment</a>
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:id>/commentform/', views.CommentForm, name='commentform'),
]
```

Views

```
def CommentForm(request, id=None):
    print('1')
    testimony=get_object_or_404(Testimony, id=id)
    print('2')
    print('3')
    form=CommentForm(request)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=CommentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        print('d')
        if form.is_valid():
            print('e')
            comment=form.save(commit=False)
            comment.testimony=testimony
            comment.save()
            return redirect('details', id=testimony.id)
        else:
            form=CommentForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    return render(request, 'comment_form.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Can you please check in the Database if `Testimony` table has any entry for primary key 34?

Comment: Yes it does. My detail view works.